Drivers Broken When Opened in Blender 4.2?
I have some drivers working perfectly fine in 3.0 series that are breaking in 4.2 when opened. Any ideas as to what could be causing this break and if there is a fast solution?
3.0 series

4.2 Series


You can try opening your file in latest stable Blender 3.x (3.6.14)  If it works, save it again, and open in Blender 4.0. If it works, save again and open in any Blender 4.x (e.g. 4.2). If this doesn't work, reduce your file to contain as little as possible, ideally just 2 elements and one driver that works in Blender 3.x and doesn't in Blender 4.x. Then upload a .blend file to share it. How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice keep in mind if it turns out to be a bug it will be off-topic to this site.

Good tip, I'll try this, thank you
